# How do i make it so that my button becomes a pop field with same information instead of directing it into a different page?

Tags: javascript, json, popup, storage

So I have added a highscore page with code that stores and changes the score and adds the name of the username to a different page. What i would like is that when i click the button HighScore it becomes a pop up window instead. But dont know how to do it.

I know that it is mostly code that i have linked and iam sorry but i wanted to link all code that have with highscore to do. All i really want is a popup window when i click the button that shows the exact same data that the highscore page shows.

I have added all relevant code.

```js
//highscore.js
//constants
const highScoresList = document.getElementById("highScoresList");
const highScores = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("highScores")) || [];

//mapping
highScoresList.innerHTML = highScores
  .map(score => {
    return `<li class="high-score">${score.name} - ${score.score}</li>`;
  })
  .join("");
//end.js
//Constants
const username = document.getElementById('username');
const saveScoreBtn = document.getElementById('saveScoreBtn');
const finalScore = document.getElementById('finalScore');
const mostRecentScore = localStorage.getItem('mostRecentScore');
const highScores = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('highScores')) || [];
const MAX_HIGH_SCORES = 5;

//Event Listener
finalScore.innerText = mostRecentScore;
username.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    saveScoreBtn.disabled = !username.value;
});
//Save high score
saveHighScore = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const score = {
        score: mostRecentScore,
        name: username.value,
    };
    highScores.push(score);
    highScores.sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score);
    highScores.splice(5);

    localStorage.setItem('highScores', JSON.stringify(highScores));
    window.location.assign('/');
};
//Game.js
getNewQuestion = () => {
    if (availableQuestions.length === 0 || questionCounter >= MAX_QUESTIONS) {
        localStorage.setItem("mostRecentScore", score);
        //go to the end page
        return window.location.assign('/end.html');
    }
    questionCounter++;
    progressText.innerText = `Question ${questionCounter}/${MAX_QUESTIONS}`;
    //update the progress progress bar
    progressBarFull.style.width = `${(questionCounter / MAX_QUESTIONS) * 100}%`;
    const questionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableQuestions.length);
    currentQuestion = availableQuestions[questionIndex];
    question.innerText = currentQuestion.question;
    choices.forEach( choice => {
        const number = choice.dataset['number'];
        choice.innerText = currentQuestion['choice' + number];
    });
    availableQuestions.splice(questionIndex, 1);
    acceptingAnswers = true;
};
```

```html
//endpage
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Congrats!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/app.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="end" class="flex-center flex-column">
        <h1 id="finalScore"></h1>
        <form>
          <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username"/>
          <button type="submit" class="btn" id="saveScoreBtn" onclick="saveHighScore(event)" disabled>
            Save
          </button>
        </form>
        <a class="btn" href="/game.html">Play Again</a>
        <a class="btn" href="/">Go Home</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/assets/js/end.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

//highscore page
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>High Scores</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/highscores.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="highScores" class="flex-center flex-column">
            <h1 id="finalScore">High Scores</h1>
            <ul id="highScoresList"></ul>
            <a class="btn" href="/">Go Home</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/assets/js/highscores.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using `bootstrap`? Seems like `Modal` is what you need https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: I was looking at that, but i could not understand how i would apply all JS to that text and such. So that the high score page would be in that modal. That's the part i don't understand how to do.

Answer (score 0):

For non Bootstrap solution, reference [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp).

If you do have Bootstrap, you may reference the following as example.

Full documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/).

Add this to endpage's body

```
<div class="modal" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h1 id="finalScore">High Scores</h1>
        <ul id="highScoresList"></ul>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the button that gonna trigger it:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  See High Score
</button>
```